# Lubuntu 32-bit, How to get Panoramio images to work in Google Earth

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, google-earth

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 on a 32-bit ThinkPad T60. As a matter of course, Panoramio images won't show up in Google Earth; all solutions (one, really) around the Web concern 64-bit Linux. Is there a way to get it to work on a 32-bit system? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for Google Earth 7 in Ubuntu 32 bit yet.

But you can use Google Earth 6, for example from there: [googleearth_6.0.2.2074](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/import/g/googleearth/googleearth_6.0.2.2074-r0-1mint2_i386.deb)

In this version Panoramio images works well.